# Передать значение переменной в другой класс в одном файле

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Нужно передать значение переменной "value" из класса ParseTask метода
 doInBackground в класс MapsActivity для использования в тосте.

```
class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {

    var GLOBAL_POS: LatLng? = null//для передачи latlng в MainActivity



    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
            var secPos = mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(myPos)).setVisible(true)
            GLOBAL_POS = myPos
            ParseTask(GLOBAL_POS).execute()


        }
    }


class ParseTask(GLOBAL_POS: LatLng?) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Int>() {
    private var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    private var reader: BufferedReader? = null
    private var resultJson = ""
    var GLOBAL_VAR: Int = 0

    private var GLOBAL_LAT = GLOBAL_POS!!.latitude
    private var GLOBAL_LNG = GLOBAL_POS!!.longitude


    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Int? {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {

            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection!!.requestMethod = "GET"
            urlConnection!!.connect()

            val inputStream = urlConnection!!.inputStream
            val buffer = StringBuffer()

            reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

            var line: String?
            do {
                line = reader!!.readLine()
                if (line == null)
                    break
                buffer.append(line)
            } while (true)

            resultJson = buffer.toString()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        try {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                    .build()

            val request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build()

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                    val responseString = response!!.body()!!.string()

                    val resultJson = JSONObject(responseString)

                    val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
                    val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
                    val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
                    val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
                    val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
                    var value = distance.getInt("value")
                    value /= 1000
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + value)
                    GLOBAL_VAR = value
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "some error")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return GLOBAL_VAR
    }
    companion object {
        var LOG_TAG = "my_log"
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите код, который не относится к вопросу. Воспроизведите проблему на минимальном примере (почитайте «[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)» в справке)

Comment: Зачем Вам `AsyncTask`, если запрос и так асинхронный? Просто делайте что нужно в `onResponse`

Comment: Я делал по примерам в интернете. Вообще единственное решение, которое у меня заработало как нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто же так делает?

Во-первых, вы запускаете один AsyncTask, а результат пытаетесь вытянуть совсем из другого объекта

```
ParseTask().execute() // это первый объект, запускается
var parseTask:ParseTask = ParseTask() // это уже новый объект, и он ничего не делал, результатов не содержит

GLOBAL_VAR_JSON = parseTask.GLOBAL_VAR // конечно тут ВСЕГДА будет null
```

Во-вторых, а как же дождаться завершения асинхронной операции? Нельзя сразу после запуска смотреть результат, его скорее всего еще не будет.

В-третьих, Retrofit сам по себе асинхронный, для работы с ним никаких AsyncTask не нужно.

Comment: Это OkHttp. Как дождаться завершения операции? В логи всё отображается сразу, мне нужно вытянуть в MainActivity.